# traveller's cheques; customer's requirements: use of the singular Saxon genitive (and the plural attributive) for association

Tags: grammar

May I ask if the following sentence is grammatical?

> Our remit is to conduct research on customer's requirements.

In my understanding, as 'customer' is a countable noun, so the plural form 'customers''' should be used instead for this general reference (without specification of certain customers).

However, I know that we can say 'traveller's cheques' - e.g.,

> Traveller's cheques are available at the bank.

In this sense, actually can we say 'customer's requirements' in the first case?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I have formatted it. Is it more readable now?

Answer (score 4):

At the thread [Is it correct to say 'I write children books' ... not using the possessive case?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case/92364#92364) one finds

> There is a move away from the use of the apostrophe in the
> 'adjectival' (rather than the 'true possessive') sense you mention
> here. However, the tendency is to just drop the apostrophe rather than
> switch to an unusual-sounding singular modifying noun:
>
> Childrens Home
>
> Dogs Home
>
> Travellers Rest
>
> Working Mens Club
>
> Mens Clothing Department.

It's interesting that the aid to driving invented by Percy Shaw of Halifax (UK) was called the *cat's eye*, plural *cat's eyes*, but that nowadays the modern forms *cats eye / cats eyes* are usually used.

Correspondingly, the unapostrophised **travellers cheques** is the more modern usage, as can be found say at [Editex](https://editex.com/an-apostrophe-catastrophe/). Though many dictionaries still give the older **traveller's cheques**. (This may seem the less logical possessive choice, meaning 'cheques for travellers' as it does, but corresponding to 'cheques for the [average] traveller'.)

However, *customers' requirements* is by no means so fossilised (*travellers cheque/s* has achieved compound noun status). But the modern trend would require the  attributive noun usage **customer requirements** (using the singular-form attributive noun, as is the usual case).

This is supported by [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=customer+requirements%2Ccustomer%27s+requirements%2Ccustomers%27+requirements%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccustomer%20requirements%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccustomer%20%27s%20requirements%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccustomers%20%27%20requirements%3B%2Cc0) (which also show the near-equality in the use of *customer's requirements* and *customers' requirements* ...  though they fail to distinguish the generic and the non-generic usages of both  *customer's requirements* and *customers' requirements*).

Comment: Thanks @Edwin! So 'customer requirements' would be the most commonly used version nowadays; and 'customers' requirements' is also correct but old-fashioned. May I further ask if there is any difference between 'customers' requirements' and 'customer's requirements'. I guess the former carries an emphasis on the variety of customers, which is absent in the latter? Thx!

Comment: One would of course use the apostrophe to show possession (or at least attachment to a particular person or group of persons): 'Fred and Mary Smythe said they needed a Luggo blue whale kit pronto. We could not find one in stock in any of our stores: we failed to meet these customers' requirements. But Ali Khan asked for a kit tyrannosaur; we were able to meet that customer's requirements.' // If one insists on an apostrophised form for the generic case, although the Google Ngrams do not force this (the generic usage), there seems little to choose between _customer's ..._

Comment: _requirements_ and _customers' requirements_. The emphasis you mention may exist, but using a singular to stand in for what might logically be expected to be a plural is not unheard of (eg _traveller's cheques_).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, Edwin! They're helpful!