# Does Leaders Guide have an apostrophe?

Tags: apostrophe

Using a leaders guide in a doctoral dissertation, does the title "Leaders Guide" have an apostrophe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [traveller's cheques; customer's requirements: use of the singular Saxon genitive (and the plural attributive) for association](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/523431/travellers-cheques-customers-requirements-use-of-the-singular-saxon-genitive) Essentially, the apostrophised versions are rather old-fashioned now, and the plural attributive form is often chosen for associative-rather-than-truly-possessive examples.

Answer (score 1):

"Leaders" here looks like an *attributive noun*, and so would not need the apostrophe. A relatively clear explanation can be found here: https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012

According to that page (which lists its sources, though it's hard to say which one this is from):

> The apostrophe is omitted when a plural head noun ending in s functions as an adjective rather than as a possessor

Presumably the guide is not *possessed by* leaders but is written to guide leaders. So you would not need an apostrophe in this case.

Comment: Did you find the answers at the duplicate inadequate?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Apologies! I did not follow the links in your comment but for no good reason assumed they were external links. My bad.

Comment: just curious as to why the downvote. this answer does in fact add to the information provided in the link in the comment.

Comment: There are so many previous answers. See, for instance, [attributive or possessive noun? the Dell Company's staff or the Dell Company staff](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114531/attributive-or-possessive-noun-the-dell-companys-staff-or-the-dell-company-st) (itself closed as a duplicate). It is not helpful to have a different question posted for every conceivable example. And ignoring claimed duplicates ("Apologies. I did not follow") is a sure way to increase bloatware. And 'There is a move away from the use of the apostrophe ...

Comment: in the 'adjectival' (rather than the 'true possessive') sense' is quite clear; there is a further link to the original source.