# Leaders Trip or Leaders' Trip

Tags: possessives

Hoping for some assistance with my possessive conundrum.

If you were going on a trip for leaders (not run by leaders/organised by leaders), would it be: a Leaders Trip or Leaders' Trip?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in "‑s"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think it quite does. I'm wondering whether this needs an apostrophe at all since the trip doesn't belong to the leaders as such.

Comment: This is a question about whether to treat "Leaders" as a noun adjunct.

Comment: Do [St Matthews vs St Matthew, referring to a church?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134886/st-matthews-vs-st-matthew/134897#134897) or [traveller's cheques; customer's requirements: use of the singular Saxon genitive (and the plural attributive) for association](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/523431/travellers-cheques-customers-requirements-use-of-the-singular-saxon-genitive/523436#523436) provide a satisfactory answer?  Essentially, many would drop the apostrophe (but not the "s"), and quite a few would get offended at this.