# Events Calendar or Event Calendar

Tags: grammatical-number

Which form is *more* correct?

- **Events Calendar**

  - ex. [Brooklyn Public Library](https://www.bklynlibrary.org/calendar/list)
  - [The](https://theeventscalendar.com/)
  - ex. [NYC Parks](https://www.nycgovparks.org/events)
- **Event Calendar**

  - ex. [Botanic Garden](https://www.bbg.org/visit/calendar)
  - ex. [Barclays Center](https://www.barclayscenter.com/events-tickets/event-calendar)

[NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=events+calendar%2Cevent+calendar&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&case_insensitive=on&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [User’s Guide vs Users’ Guide](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36657/user-s-guide-vs-users-guide) Answers there cover singular / plural as well as possessive / "noun adjunct"

Comment: Not to be confused with the [**advent calendar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advent_calendar)

Comment: With such choices, it's usually the single-form attributive noun version that predominates. Apparently not in this case. But both variants are very common; 'more correct' is not a helpful concept here.

Comment: From [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) article they have example of "arms race" as a lexical exception. When I think of a calendar, I think of *many events* being displayed on (or having) a *single* calendar. Does that mean plural "Events' Calendar" can become "Events Calendar" by dropping apostrophe. If single-form usually predominates ... therefore it's fine to use "Event Calendar"?

Comment: What @EdwinAshworth said. Apparently, although we favour plural [***events** calendar*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+event+calendar%2Can+events+calendar&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), the more-common-overall *singular* reasserts itself with [*an **appointment** calendar*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+appointment+calendar%2Can+appointments+calendar&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) I'm sure "correct" is a worthless concept here, and I seriously doubt there's any meaningful *reason* for that difference!

Comment: 'A lexical exception' seems too categorical; there are quite a few examples where the attributive noun is customarily, perhaps necessarily, plural-form (sports reporter / systems analyst / travellers cheque / dogs home or dogs' home / ...). // 'Events' Calendar' looks outlandish. In the UK, the new form _mens_ has appeared; _working mens clubs_ is the more usual form nowadays. Even _childrens clothing department_ is considered the better option by some (though my spell-checker is flagging it)....

Comment: See [travellers'/traveller's cheques; customers'/customer's requirements ... use of the-singular-form Saxon genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/523431/travellers-cheques-customers-requirements-use-of-the-singular-saxon-genitive/523436#523436).